# c# Drawing bitmap over another one

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, bitmap

I'm working on a project,and i need to draw  blocks of images(as bitmaps)  which i receive from a socket on an already existing image (which i define in the beggining of the program),and to display it on a `PictureBox`-in other words,to update the image everytime i receive a new block.

In order to do this asynchronously, i use a `Thread`  which read the data from the `Socket` and process it.

This is my code:

```
private void MainScreenThread() {

ReadData();
initial = bufferToJpeg(); //full screen first shot.
pictureBox1.Image = initial;

while (true) {
 int pos = ReadData();
 int x = BlockX();
 int y = BlockY();
 Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg(); //retrieveing the new block.

 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(initial);
 g.DrawImage(block, x, y); //drawing the new block over the inital image.
 this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Refresh())); //refreshing the picturebox-will update the intial;

 }
}
  private Bitmap bufferToJpeg()
    {
      return (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);        
    }
```

I'm getting an error

> object is currently in use elsewhere

On the `Graphics` creation line

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(initial);
```

I'm not using any other threads or somthing ot access the bitmap..so i'm not sure what's the problem here..

If anyone can enlighten me i'll be really thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: You just discovered that neither the PictureBox nor the Bitmap class are thread-safe.  Mercifully the Bitmap class has a diagnostic built in for that, kaboom when you use Graphics.FromImage() at the exact same time that the PictureBox repaints itself.  Pretty random, like threading race bugs always are.  You need to invoke more code, also Graphics.FromImage and DrawImage.  Or create your own thread-safe PictureBox class, its OnPaint() override needs to take a lock that you also take in this method.

Comment: You are likely going to run in to a `OutOfMemoryException` pretty quickly with this, you need to dispose `block` within each loop and dispose of `g` when you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign the graphics before the loop:

```
private void MainScreenThread() {

  ReadData();
  initial = bufferToJpeg(); 
  pictureBox1.Image = initial;
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(initial);

  while (true) {
    int pos = ReadData();
    int x = BlockX();
    int y = BlockY();
    Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg(); 

    g.DrawImage(block, x, y); 
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Refresh())); 

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its because you never dispose the graphics object after its being used.

If you look at the graphics component, when you create it. You use the "initial" bitmap. The graphics are now pointing at this "initial" object, first time it will succeed to create the graphics but second time (since the 'g' has not been disposed/been released) the "initial" object is still being in use by the old graphics before creating a new one.

What you can do is:

```
private void MainScreenThread() {

   ReadData();
   initial = bufferToJpeg(); //full screen first shot.
   pictureBox1.Image = initial;

   while (true) {
    int pos = ReadData();
    int x = BlockX();
    int y = BlockY();
    Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg(); //retrieveing the new block.

    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(initial)) {
       g.DrawImage(block, x, y); //drawing the new block over the inital image.
       this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Refresh())); //refreshing the picturebox-will update the intial;
   }
 }
}
```

What will happen is that the 'g' object will be disposed after being used so that you can do the same operation again afterwards.

**Edit**: Fix- Didnt properly include the whole code as a code block.

Comment: i also thought about it, so i used `Dispose` before, and now i use the `Using()` statement...unfortunately im getting exactly the same error....on the same line...`object is currently in use elsewhere` @Karl Patrik Johansson

Comment: Hmm, then it must be because its being used by the picture box? Perhaps try and clone the initial bitmap before creating the graphics and assign the cloned bitmap as the new image on the picturebox. ex: `var img = (Bitmap)initial.Clone(); using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))` and then `this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Image = img));`

Comment: now i'm getting the error on the creation of the clone in this line `var img= (Bitmap)initial.Clone();` @Karl Patrik Johansson

Comment: can you post the `bufferToJpeg()` method? perhaps theres something in that one that causes the image to be "locked"

Comment: im quite sure our problem is not there :) .
Updated my code in the question.

Comment: @Slashy your updated code still has the bug of not disposing of the graphics object